# Document() XSLT 2.0 can't acess to xml child element ( Saxon CE 1.1)

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a stylesheet that loads an XML file using document() function after retrieving this xml file I can't access any of it's children elements, the only this that i can get is the hole document : document('parameters') will show the hole document content but when calling document('parameters')/total_time nothing appears

XML Document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters 
xmlns="http://www.duniptechnologies.com/binding/Coupled" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.duniptechnologies.com/binding/Coupled/parameters.xsd">
<total_time>100.2</total_time>
<external_events>
    <event>
        <message>go to red</message>
        <model>red_light</model>
        <port>15</port>
        <time>150</time>
    </event>
    <event>
        <message>go to red</message>
        <model>red_light</model>
        <port>15</port>
        <time>180</time>
    </event>
</external_events>
<Initialization>
    <model name="Atomic1">Atomic1</model>
    <model name="Atomic2">Atomic2</model>
    <model name="Coupled">Coupled</model>
    <model name="SousAtomic1">SousAtomic1</model>
    <model name="SousCoupled1">SousCoupled1</model>
    <model name="SouSouAtomic1">SouSouAtomic1</model>
</Initialization>
</parameters>
```

XSLT Document

```
<xsl:stylesheet xpath-default-
namespace="http://www.duniptechnologies.com/binding/Coupled" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:prop="http://saxonica.com/ns/html-property" 
xmlns:style="http://saxonica.com/ns/html-style-property" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:ixsl="http://saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT" 
xmlns:js="http://saxonica.com/ns/globalJS" extension-element-prefixes="ixsl" 
version="2.0">
<xsl:template match("/rootelemnt")>
    <xsl:value-of select="document('parameters.xml')/total_time/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Correction

replace

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('parameters.xml')/total_time/text()"/>
```

By

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('parameters.xml')/parameters/total_time/text()"/>
```

Comment: `xsl:template match("/")` is not even close to correct syntax so I am sure you won't get that stylesheet executed at all. As for the path `document('parameters.xml')/total_time`, well, if the XML you have shown is the one you load there then you need to use `document('parameters.xml')/parameters/total_time`.

Comment: Hello @MartinHonnen thanx for the help it worked

Comment: As a general point, I would advise migrating from Saxon-CE to Saxon-JS. The technology used to build Saxon-CE (the GWT toolkit) is dated and difficult to support, and we won't be producing any new releases or fixing bugs; in addition it's based on a fork of Saxon 9.3 which itself is past its shelf life.